# Gmap module - disable scroll

Tags: google-maps

I have installed the latest version 7.x-2.11
And after selecting the option "nomousezoom : Disable mouse zoom".

I can still scroll over the map using my mouse.

Is this a known bug? is there a patch and if so how do I use it?